# Transverse DOM in a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

I've dumped response of `XMLHttpRequest()` into a variable of a website for example, yahoo.com. How I need to get values of DOM content by `getElementById` or `getElementsByName` of this variable.

***For example:***

```
var dump; //contains html source code of a website e.g. yahoo.com
var data = dump.getElementsByTagName('span').value;
// it's throw error "Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementsByTagName is not defined"
```

Now, I need to get SPAN tags values from variable dump.

Is that possible or any another way to retrieve those datas by using javascript or jquery alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work with jquery:

https://jsfiddle.net/q0r3fem6/

```
var dump = "<html><body><div><span value='xyz'>test</span></div><body></html>";
console.log( $(dump).find("span").attr("value") );
console.log( $(dump).find("span").text() );
```

Alternatively you could append dump to your document and read it from there.

Comment: thanks! `$(dump).find("span[class^='something']:first").text();` _//alternate way to get first span tag with attribute of class is something_

Comment: yup.. should work with any css selector/path and jquery method for your traversing needs ;)